# Take milliseconds from localtime (without Boost!) in C

Tags: c, milliseconds, localtime

How can we do this (get local time with milliseconds) without Boost?
I have something like this:

```
time_of_day = time(NULL);

time_str_tm = localtime(&time_of_day);

printf("\n%02i:%02i:%02i\n", time_str_tm->tm_hour, time_str_tm->tm_min, time_str_tm->tm_sec);
```

but the `tm` structure has only seconds at last...

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `gettimeofday(2)`

```
struct timeval time_now;
gettimeofday(&time_now, NULL);
time_str_tm = gmtime(&time_now.tv_sec);

printf("\n%02i:%02i:%02i:%06i\n"
   , time_str_tm->tm_hour
   , time_str_tm->tm_min
   , time_str_tm->tm_sec
   , time_now.tv_usec);
```

Comment: I had `gettimeofday` first, but I should avoid it for some reasons that my tutor can`t explain to me.. 
Is there any ways to avoid it? And do something with `localtime`?

Comment: @Ksenia No standard way that I am aware of. `gettimeofday` is standardised in both  4.3BSD and POSIX.1-2001, so I am sceptical why your tutor doesn't want you to use it.

Comment: By the way, `tv_usec` is a microseconds not millisecinds.. Should I devide `tv_usec` by million?

Comment: @Ksenia Yes, just divide it by 1000 if you don't need the additional precision :)

Comment: what is the difference between `localtime` and `gmtime`?

Comment: @Ksenia `localtime` gets the current time and returns a pointer to `struct tm`. `gmtime` converts a supplied `time_t` to a `struct tm`. Since there is a small delay between calling `gettimeofday` and `gmtime` it's better to reuse the result from `gettimeofday`.

Comment: You`re much better than my tutor :) Thank you a lot! Your code works as I need to.